# angular calendar detect month change event

Tags: angularjs, events, calendar

I have the following issue while using the angular ui calendar component, as when the page loads I have like 60 records (full of information) I pull off the DB and this makes the reloading really awfull.

I realize I could detect when the user switches from one month to another and so load only the records corresponding to that month (According to the view).

Is there any angular ui calendar event to detect or be aware of this ?. Thankx !.

Comment: Are you talking about datepicker or calender?

Comment: I am using the Angular UI Calendar from this page: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

This is pulled from docs:

**Custom event rendering**

You can use fullcalendar's eventRender option to customize how events are rendered in the calendar. However, only certain event attributes are watched for changes (they are `id, title, url, start, end, allDay`, and `className`).

If you need to automatically re-render other event data, you can use calendar-watch-event. calendar-watch-event expression must return a function that is passed event as argument and returns a string or a number, for example:

```
$scope.extraEventSignature = function(event) {
   returns "" + event.price;
}

<ui-calendar calendar-watch-event="extraEventSignature(event)" ... >
// will now watch for price
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#watching-the-displayed-date-range-of-the-calendar), it is advised to use `viewRender` callback:

> There is no mechanism to $watch the displayed date range on the
>   calendar due to the JQuery nature of fullCalendar. If you want to
>   track the dates displayed on the calendar so you can fetch events
>   outside the scope of fullCalendar (Say from a caching store in a
>   service, instead of letting fullCalendar pull them via AJAX), you can
>   add the viewRender callback to the calendar config.

```
$scope.calendarConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: "100%",
        ...
        viewRender: function(view, element) {
            console.log("View Changed: ", view.start, view.end);
        }
    }
};
```